# How to convert this add-to-list call into a function

Tags: elisp, functions

I have a bunch of add-to-list calls that I'd like to shorten in my `.emacs` file. They all look like this:

```
 (add-to-list 'align-rules-list
              '(haskell-comment
                (regexp . "\\(\\s-+\\)--\\s-+")
                (mode   . '(haskell-mode))
                (repeat . nil)))
```

I don't know lisp but I tried to define a local function that I can call repeatedly. I'm not getting very far:

```
(let ((f (lambda (name re)
          (add-to-list
           'align-rules-list
           (list name
                 ('regexp . re)
                 '(mode . (haskell-mode))
                 '(repeat . nil))))))
 (funcall f 'haskell-comment "\\(\\s-+\\)--\\s-+"))
```

Can someone point out my problem with the code above?

---

After much googling, I've arrived at something that seems to work:

```
(let ((f (lambda (name re)
          (add-to-list
           'align-rules-list
           (list name
                 (cons 'regexp re)
                 '(mode . '(haskell-mode))
                 '(repeat . nil))))))
 (funcall f 'haskell-comment "\\(\\s-+\\)--\\s-+")
```

But it seems messy. Quotes everywhere, `cons`, `list`. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3):

[`defmacro`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Macros.html) is perfect for such use cases.

```el
(defmacro my/add-to-align-rules-list-haskell (name re)
  `(add-to-list 'align-rules-list
                '(,name
                  (regexp . ,re)
                  (mode   . '(haskell-mode))
                  (repeat . nil))))
(my/add-to-align-rules-list-haskell haskell-comment "\\(\\s-+\\)--\\s-+")
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you given the set of rule names and corresponding regexps?
Assuming you have them in a list, just iterate over the list.

```el
(defvar rule+regexp-alist '((haskell-comment . "\\(\\s-+\\)--\\s-+") (foo . "re1") (bar . "re2"))
  "(RULE . REGEXP) pairs, where RULE is a symbol and REGEXP is a string.")

(dolist (rl+re  rule+regexp-alist) 
  (add-to-list 'align-rules-list `(,(car rl+re)
                                   (regexp . ,(cdr rl+re))
                                   (mode 'haskell-mode)
                                   (repeat))))
```

(But are you sure it is `'haskell-mode` you want in the result, instead of just `haskell-mode`?  IOW, you want `(mode 'haskell-mode)` in the result, not just `(mode haskell-mode)`?)

(Yes, I ignored your request to "convert to a function", as I don't see the point of that, from your description.  Sounds like you just want to make several similar calls to `add-to-list`.  If so, then just do that - factor out the "similar" parts and iterate over the list of dissimilar parts.)

Answer (score 1):

> But it seems messy. Quotes everywhere, cons, list. Is there a cleaner way?

This should be what you're looking for.

```
`(,name 
  (regexp . ,re)
  (mode . (haskell-mode)) 
  (repeat . nil))
```

This is usually called the backquote, quasi-quote, or backtick.

---

Meanwhile, instead of let-binding `f` as a variable, you can use `cl-flet` which will let you use `f` as an actual function name. (Or you can just define a global function/macro, it's just a config file after all.) ;-)